# Plotting a function and a derivative function

Tags: r, plot, derivative

I would like to plot a dataframe (X,Y) `data` together with a fitted function **and** the derivative of the fitted function.

```
fit <- lm(data$Y ~ poly(data$X,32,raw=TRUE))
data$fitted_values <- predict(fit, data.frame(x=data$X))
```

As far as I understood, this gives me a polynomial function of the 32nd degree, `fit`, that I use to calculate the function values and store them in `data$fitted`. Plotting these series works like a charm with `ggplot2`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=X)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = Y), colour="red") + 
    geom_line(aes(y = predict), colour="blue")
```

[image: Plot]

So far so good. But what I'm would like to plot too is the first derivative, `data$Y'`, of the fitted function `fit`. What I'm interested in is the gradient of the fitted function.

**My Question**: How can I get the derivative function of `fit`?
I assume I can then "predict" the absolute values for plotting afterwards. Correct?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example, for example by doing `dput(data)` and editing in the result? It would make it easier to demonstrate a solution. (Incidentally, you might want to show `Y` as `geom_point` rather than `geom_line`!)

Comment: You can estimate the derivative point-by-point using [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/304664). Alternatively, since you know the form of the fit (a polynomial of degree 32 with coefficients `coef(fit)`), you can write a simple function to manually take the derivative, which is very simple for polynomials.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, i'll create some test data that "kind of" looks like yours

```
set.seed(15)
rr<-density(faithful$eruptions)
dd<-data.frame(x=rr$x)
dd$y=rr$y+ runif(8,0,.05)

fit <- lm(y ~ poly(x,32,raw=TRUE), dd)
dd$fitted <- fitted(fit)

ggplot(dd, aes(x=x)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = y), colour="red") + 
    geom_line(aes(y = fitted), colour="blue")
```

[image]

Then, because you have a special form of a polynomial we can easily calculate the derivative by multiplying each of the coefficients by the power and shifting all the terms down. Here's a helper function to calcualte the new coefficients

```
deriv_coef<-function(x) {
    x <- coef(x)
    stopifnot(names(x)[1]=="(Intercept)")
    y <- x[-1]
    stopifnot(all(grepl("^poly", names(y))))
    px <- as.numeric(gsub("poly\\(.*\\)","",names(y)))
    rr <- setNames(c(y * px, 0), names(x))
    rr[is.na(rr)] <- 0
    rr
}
```

which we can use like...

```
dd$slope <- model.matrix(fit) %*% matrix(deriv_coef(fit), ncol=1)
```

And now I can plot

```
ggplot(dd, aes(x=x)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = y), colour="red") + 
    geom_line(aes(y = fitted), colour="blue") + 
    geom_line(aes(y = slope), colour="green")
```

[image]

and we can see that the inflection points correspond to places where the derivative is zero.

Answer (score 4):

You can approximate the derivative by first sorting the data with respect to `X`, then finding the differences between each pair of consecutive values.

```
data <- d[order(d$X), ]
data$derivative = c(diff(d$fitted_values) / diff(d$X), NA)
```

(Note how I added an `NA` to the end, since taking the differences makes it slightly shorter). Afterwards you can plot this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(X, derivative)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Thank you David! This works and is a pragmatic solution for the problem at hand! But also, as far as I understood it, the solution of MrFlick is the mathematically correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Allegedly the quantchem package can do it with the derivative function.

> **Description**
>
> Calculate derivative of polynomial for given x.
>
> **Usage**
>
> derivative(obj, x)
>
> **Arguments**
>
> *obj*:     an object of class 'lm', fitted in y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3) + ...
> way.
>
> *x*:   a vector of x values
>
> **Examples**
>
> x = 1:10 y = jitter(x+x^2)
>
> fit = lm(y~x+I(x^2))
>
> derivative(fit,1:10)

[Source](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/quantchem/html/derivative.html)

Note: All of this said, it didn't work for me and my data.